# In Python how to construct a str for help(object)

Tags: python

I need a str object created out of the text displayed in help(some_object).
simply typecasting to str doesn't work.

```
>>> s = str(help(object))
>>> print s
None
```

Whats the correct way to do this ?

Comment: If you just want the object's docstring, which is pretty much what you get from `help` for `object`, you can just `print object.__doc__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print pydoc.text.document(object)
class object
 |  The most base type
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me :) I just need to know one more thing if pydocs module is shipped by default with python2.6+. Is it so ?

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html), considering that's what `help()` uses in the first place.

Comment: Interesting: `help("import")` gives a lot of text, but `pydoc.text.document("import")` returns `"'import'"`.  Doesn't mean this answer is wrong, but it seemed worth pointing out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You actually want:

```
import pydoc
strhelp = pydoc.render_doc(str, "Help on %s")
```

That'll get you the *exact* text produced by `help(str)`.